# Flask display dropdowns based on the selection on other dropdown

Tags: python, flask

I am new to flask and honestly don't know where to start for the given problem. I have a dropdown list, when I select the number from the list the program should display other drop down lists. For example, if I choose 1 it will show Option 1: dropdown, and if I choose 2 it will show both Option 1: and Option 2: dropdown (See the picture). There may be other ways to do it, but I need it in Flask.

Picture

[image]

Comment: This has absolutely nothing do do with Flask. It's front-end.

Comment: Ah ok! I am a naive in this domain, didn't realize that. Any idea on that direction.